# TYPO3 foreign_table: How to specify a specific column to a select drop down menu?

Tags: select, typo3

I want to add records in the TYPO3 backend. For that I made an extension containing 4 different classes. While adding a record of one specific class to a folder via the backend I want to have a select that lets me chose from items of a column from another class. I know I have to use a `foreign_table` for this like in this code:

```
 'kundeuid' => array(
                   'exclude' => 1,
                   'label' => 'LLL:EXT:icingaconfgen/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_icingaconfgen_domain_model_appliance.kundeuid',
                   'config' => array(
                                   'type' => 'select',
                                   'renderType' => 'selectSingle',
                                   'foreign_table' => 'tx_icingaconfgen_domain_model_kunde',
                                   'foreign_table_where' => 'ORDER BY tx_icingaconfgen_domain_model_kunde.kundeuid asc',
                                   'items' => array(
                                                   array('-- Select Kunde --', 0),
                                   ),
                                   'size' => 1,
                                   'maxitems' => 1
                   ),
           ),
```

But the problem is I can't specify that the selection should only include properties of a determined column. Instead the select drop down menu seems to use properties of the very first column. How can I specify the column of the 'kundeuid' property?

Edit: I forgot to mention, the code is used in the specific PHP file in the TCA folder.

Comment: Do you just want to change the label field of the select items or their values to a value other than the "uid" of the foreign records?

Comment: I try to be more specific: The class 'Kunde' has a property 'kundeuid'. While adding a record of the class 'Appliance' in the backend which has the same property (basically the foreign key so to speak) this property should be set by a select drop down which contains the 'kundeuid' values of all the existing objects/records of the class 'Kunde'. I want to do this by using the foreign_table in the specific TCA for the class 'Appliance'. The above code even loads properties of 'Kunde' records, but it seems to use the wrong colums/properties...

Comment: So the 'Kunde' records got a property 'uid' of TYPO3 but another property named "kundeuid" which you want to store?

Comment: No, both classes... Kunde and Appliance have the property 'kundeuid'...
If i add an Appliance i want to set its kundeuid from a selection based on the Kunde objects.

Basically every Appliance belongs to a specific Kunde. That's why Appliance has the kundeuid as a foreign key so to speak.

Comment: I just understood you question from yesterday: "Do you just want to change the label field of the select items or their values to a value other than the "uid" of the foreign records?"

The second option is what i want to do. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Creating a select from field values of another table

You can fill the select with whatever you want if you implement a PHP method that provides the content of the select box. For this you have to use `itemsProcFunc`.

Could look like this:

```
'kundeuid' => [
     'config' => [
        'type' => 'select',
        'renderType' => 'selectSingle',
        'itemsProcFunc' => 'Vendor\Ext\ItemsProcFunc\KundeUid->fetchItems',
    ],
]
```

In your method you can then fill the `items` array with the values from your kunde table (look in the database yourself):

```
/**
 * Add two items to existing ones
 *
 * @param $params
 */
public function fetchItems(&$params)
{
    $params['items'][] = ['customer01 (label)', 'customer01'];
    $params['items'][] = ['customer02 (label)', 'customer02'];
}
```

Note that `$params` is passed by reference and the method does not need to return anything. Also whatever you write in your TCA config into `items` will be there as well. Whatever you select, the value of that option will be stored in yourdatabase field.

## Creating a relation

If you use the `'foreign_table'` in your TCA conf then you will create a relation to the foreign table, wich always means you are storing the uid of the selected record in your field (unless you are using a MM table).

In TYPO3 every recods has a `uid` that is on `auto_increment` in the database and therefore unique in each table. The following TCA configuration

```
'kundeuid' => [
     'config' => [
        'type' => 'select',
        'renderType' => 'selectSingle',
        'foreign_table' => 'tx_icingaconfgen_domain_model_kunde',
    ],
]
```

will let you choose your `kunde` records in a select box and store its `uid` in the field `kundeuid`. So if you let the property mapper resolve this dependency in your PHP code (or let extbase do it for you, if you use the repository and domain models), you will end up with something like this:

```
$appliance = $this->applianceRepository->findBySomething('something');
$kunde = $appliance->getKundeuid();
$kundeuid = $kunde->getKundeuid();
```

Therefore I would recommend that you rename the field, that the TCA configuration was for to something like `client`, So that the PHP code becomes a bit less confusing.

```
$appliance = $this->applianceRepository->findBySomething('something');
$client = $appliance->getClient();
$kundeuid = $client->getKundeuid();
```

Comment: There is a missunderstanding:  Say i'd set 'kundeuid' with the value 'customer01' or something while creating a record of the class Kunde. Then i create a record of the class 'Appliance'. It also has a property named 'kundeuid' and i want to set it through a select that is filled with the 'kundeuid' s from all the records of the class Kunde. One option of this select would be 'customer01' from the record of Kunde i created. I'd choose it and the property 'kundeuid' of the created Appliance record should be also 'customer01'...

That's what i want to do.

Comment: Well, go for an itemsProcFunc then, I added it to the answer

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot.

Comment: Sry, i'm pretty new to stackoverflow. But i did it now.

Answer (score 0):

When you will set property `label` to `Kunde`'s name table field in `ctrl` section in `Kunde` record in TCA you should see it also in `Appliance`. Maybe other properties `label_`* will be useful for you. Link to `ctrl` documentation: [TCA reference](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/8-dev/Ctrl/Index.html#label)

Comment: Thank you... I didn't look into this yet... I'm checking it out right now.

Comment: There seems to be a missunderstanding on my side perhaps. Another user asked me this:

" Do you just want to change the label field of the select items or their values to a value other than the "uid" of the foreign records?"

That's exactly what i want to do, i want to assign the values of kundeuid to a value other than the "uid" of the foreign records. Is that possible?

Comment: I think you have here two options. Use one of the hooks for datamap to save different value or to render custom items list with `itemsProcFunc` (documentation of TCA select type)

Comment: Thanks, i'll try this.